# Does Google News submission require that a website only submits news articles or can they be "how to" or "top 10 series" articles?

Tags: feeds, articles, google-news

Do you require to create a separate news category URL to submit website under Google news. Does it have to only contain news articles?  Can it also have "how to" or "top 10 series" articles?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google is very strict. It's hard to get listed. If you only have a blog then just say you are a blog.

There are guidelines and content policies available in the news publisher center

I'm being vetted at the moment